# Split if letters > at 10 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, split, string-length

I'm trying to split every words that contains more than 10 letters.

How can I do ?

I did :

```
if (item.title.length > 10){
        trace("item.length>10");
// What should I put here in order to erase the letters after the 10th one ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (item.title.length > 10){
    trace("item.length>10"); // 0

    trace(String(item.title).substring(0,10)); // if item.title is "star wars : the force" it will shows "star wars "        

    var arr:Array=String(item.title).split("");

   for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++)
   {
      trace(arr[i]);// it shows every letter in the array
   }

}
```

Comment: Thx. it certainly shows every letter in the array but I'd like to cut each words that have more than 10 letters. Exemple : "Star Wars 7 : The force", would become "Star Wars "

Comment: look again my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
    var string0:String = 'hello';
    var string1:String = 'hello this is a test string';

    // trunkate to up to 10 chars...
    string0 = string0.slice(0, 10);
    string1 = string1.slice(0, 10);

    trace('>' + string0 + '<');         // result is >hello<
    trace('>' + string1 + '<');         // result is >hello this<
```